# Why does bubbling carbon dioxide through calcium hydroxide result in a precipitate?

Tags: bond, carbon-family

Why does the addition of carbon dioxide to calcium hydroxide create the precipitate calcium carbonate? What happens chemically for such a molecule to form? How exactly do their interactions come into play?

Now CaOH isn’t terribly soluble in water but the parts that do dissolve, disassociate into their respective OH<sup>-</sup> and Ca<sup>2+</sup> ions. So when we bubble CO<sub>2</sub> through the CaOH solution the calcium ion is attracted to the partial negative charge on the oxygen atoms of carbon dioxide. So that forms CaCO<sub>2</sub> so my question is where does the other oxygen of calcium carbonate come from? Is it snatched from a hydroxide ion?

Calcium carbonate also has a resonant structure, I don’t know what that is exactly but it’s like electrons are being shared uniformly throughout a given structure so that means carbons original double bonds get disbanded too I guess? If anybody can explain what happens here as well, it would be great.

Here are my drawings, they may be simplified but it’s all I know:
[image]

[image]

Comment: There are millions of chemical reactions that just happen all the time. Why this one?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? I want to understand the interactions between the molecules and how they form the end products of calcium carbonate and water. Like the oxygens of the hydroxide groups and co2 are partially negative etc, I just want to understand how their interactions come into play

Comment: You put your comment and more rather to the question itself, for the below:

Comment: We have a policy which states that ‎you should show your thoughts, effort and attempts to answer your question yourself. It'll make us certain that ‎we aren't doing your homework for you, and that the Q/A is beneficial for broad audience.
 
As "homework class questions" are considered literal homeworks, self-study questions, puzzles, worked examples etc.

Please [edit] in your full reasoning or thoughts on this. See [Homework](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/141/7448)

Otherwise, the question may get closed.

Comment: Oh alright, it’s not a homework question I’m just curious. Will edit.

Answer (score 2):

The important thing to consider is the chemistry of [carbon dioxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_dioxide?wprov=sfla1) in water, forming [carbonic acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbonic_acid?wprov=sfla1). Note also that [calcium hydroxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calcium_hydroxide?wprov=sfla1) is at edge between being a strong or a weak base.

$$\begin{align}\
\ce{CO2 ^ + H2O &<=> CO2 . H2O} \tag{1} \\
\ce{CO2 . H2O &<=> H2CO3} \tag{2} \\
\ce{H2CO3 &<=> H+ + HCO3^-} \tag{3} \\
\ce{HCO3^- &<=>  H+  + CO3^2- } \tag{4} \\
\ce{ Ca(OH)2 &<=> CaOH+ + OH- } \tag{5} \\
\ce{CaOH+ &<=> Ca^2+ + OH-} \tag{6} \\
\ce{Ca^2+ + CO3^2-  &<=> CaCO3 v} \tag{7}
\end{align}$$

Yes, bonds in $\ce{CO3^2-}$ are equivalent, with strength and length somewhere between a single and a double bond. It is similar as  for $\ce{SO4^2-}$, $\ce{SO3^2-}$, $\ce{NO3^-}$, $\ce{ClO4^-}$, with sharing the "doublebondness" within the former two, and sharing the charge in all of them.